# Cannot upload ssl private key to parse

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, dns, parse-platform

So I have made an app with Parse and purchased a domain mydomain.in I want to route the traffic from mydomain.in to myapp.parseapp.com. Here's the complete list of steps I have performed.

1. My app is at myapp.parseapp.com. I purchased a domain, mydomain.in from GoDaddy.
2. In GoDaddy's DNS zone file section, I edited the CNAME(Alias) with host "www" 's "points to" to myapp.parseapp.com.
3. Then on GoDaddy, I redirected mydomain.in to www.mydomain.in .
4. I added host name as "www.mydomain.in" in Parse's "edit your app" settings.

**At this point, my app works absolutely fine, both mydomain.in and www.mydomain.in work correctly**

1. Now I want to open https://www.mydomain.in (establish a secure connection). So I decided using startSSL.com for this purpose.
2. I validated mydomain.in
3. I retrieved the private key and SSL certificate for domain mydomain.in and added a subdomain www.mydomain.in .
4. Then I tried uploading the key and certificate at "edit your app" settings at parse.
5. The certificate uploaded correctly but when I tried uploading the key, it said "invalid key". 
   This has prevented me from opening https://www.mydomain.in (secure connection).

Any ideas where I am wrong? Why is the key invalid?

Comment: how did you get the private key and what format is it in?

Comment: I generated a private key (by giving a key password), the key is in .key format ( It is in plain ASCII text, so I guess its the PEM format)

Comment: I should say that I generated the private key from the startSSL website. :) Thank You. I need help :)

Comment: interesting... try changing the extension to .pem

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem. Go to startSSL, Toolbox->Decrypt Private Key. Put in the data from the key file you have and enter the password you used to create it. startSSL will decrypt it. Save the decrypted text into a file. Upload this file to Parse as your private key file.